# Extend a parent method in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a class `Parent` which has a method `calculateRevenue();`

I also have a class `Child` that extends `Parent`. What I want to do is have the same method name in `Child` class `calculateRevenue();` which would call the method of the `Parent` class method, and then execute the `Child` method.

Is this possible? Or the same name will override the method functionality without the ability to call the `Parent` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

```
class Ancestor
{
    public function someMethod()
    {
        return 'foo';
    }
}

class Child extends Ancestor
{
    public function someMethod()
    {
        $results = parent::someMethod();

        return $results . ' bar';
    }
}

$c = new Child;

echo $c->someMethod() . "\n";
```

Output:  `foo bar`

[`parent` manual entry](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php)

Comment: What if there are more layers? Like GrandParent, Parent and Child. Calling parent:: in Child will call Parent, or GrandParent, or the first appearance as it goes upward the inheritance?

Comment: Inheritance works all the way up the chain. You could have 10 layers and in each one be able to reference `parent::someMethod`. If one layer doesn't define `someMethod`, then that layer will be skipped because it will exist on the one above it

Answer (score 2):

It would be something like this:

```
class Parent {
   public function calculateRevenue() {
       return 1;
   }
}

class Child extends Parent {
   public function calculateRevenue() {
       $parentRevenue = parent::calculateRevenue();
       return 1 + $parentRevenue;
   }
}
```

You must use the reserved word "parent" to call the class parent methods.

In this case the "Child" class uses the "extend" keyword to ihnerit "Parent" class methods. Now "Child" class can use all parent methods with the reserved keyword "parent".